# number guessing game in php

Tags: php, numbers

Im trying to create a number guessing game in php. I generate a random number and then compare it to the users entered guess using a while loop with if and ifelse statements inside it. the proble is i get no output once the user enters their guess. Could someone please help. my code is below

```
<?php

$rand = rand(1,100);
if (isset($_POST["guess"])) {

    $userGuess = $_POST["guess"];

    if($userGuess > 100 || $userGuess < 0){
        echo "Please guess a number between 1 and 100";
    }

    elseif($userGuess > $rand){
        echo "too high";
    }

    elseif($userGuess < $rand){
        echo "too low";
    }

    else{
        echo "correct";
        }
}


?>

<form action="task22.php" method="POST">
Guess a number between 1 and 100 <input type="integer" name="guess" />
<input type="button" value="Enter" />
form>
```

Comment: 1. Your loop is infinite since you never change `$userGuess` 2. I think you want to use `$_SESSION` to store the random number until the user guessed it, so that the user can input multiple guesses

Comment: @Rizier123 Why dont you post this as an answer? This is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `while` loop is wrong here. Just use `if` without `while`.

Comment: I still get no output with or without it

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and when I use:

```
<button name="test" > Enter
</button>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="button" value="Enter" />
```

also you dont close your form. You have: `form>` instead of: `</form>`

I dont know if this is the problem but:

```
<input type="integer" name="guess" />
```

This input type does not exist.

use:

```
<input type="number" name="guess" />
```

Comment: the form wasnt closed because it just didnt paste in when i copied it